# SQLite. SQL. Making row fields into column headings

Tags: sql, sqlite

### Tables

```
tblTracker: [ID, Date]
tblTrackerHours: [tblTracker.ID, Hour]
tblTrackerWTGStatus: [tblTracker.ID, TurbineID, Hour, TurbineStatus]
```

### Desired Output

```
Columns: Date          | Hour (from tblTrackerHours) | TurbineIDs .....>
Data:    Ordered dates | 1-24 for each date          | TurbineStatus
```

I'm struggling understand where to begin with creating an SQL statement that will do this.  Not every TurbineID has an entry for each hour or each day.

Any hints welcomed :-)

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you give an example of the desired output with example data instead of keywords?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a view, which you can create as follows:

```
create view desiredView as
select 
   t.date as DATEorWhateverYouWantToNameThisColumn, 
   h.hour as HOURorWhateverYouWantToNameThisColumn, 
   s.turbineId as TirbuneIDorWhateverYouWantToNameThisColumn, 
   s.turbineStatus as STATUSorWhateverYouWantToNameThisColumn
from
   tblTracker t,
   tblTrackerHours h,
   tblTrackerWTGStatus s
where
   h.id = t.id AND
   s.id = t.id;
```

Please note that, h.id and s.id in where clause actually the columns which are foreign keys in relevant tables.You can set each column's name using a word after **AS**. You can find the [syntax of the command here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html).
 After you have this view, you can select from it as you wish

```
select * from desiredView
```